# Web programming only, or database applications of any stripe?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

The DBA title kind of leaves the implication, for me anyway, that the site is aimed primarily at those of us who create and manage databases for online applications and similarly deployed settings.  Are questions about databases used in desktop/client-side programs (e.g. the use of CoreData in Cocoa) considered on- or off-topic here?

Comment: why wouldn't they be concidered on-topic ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What kind of questions are allowed on Database Administrators ?](http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-kind-of-questions-are-allowed-on-database-administrators)

Comment: How does the DBA title imply web based applications only?

Answer (score 6):

This site should not be limited to web only. I think desktop applications like MS-Access should be on-topic as well.

Answer (score 5):

> Are **questions about databases** used in
>   desktop/client-side programs (e.g. the
>   use of CoreData in Cocoa) considered
>   on- or off-topic here?

You answered your own question in the question itself.

As long as the question is for database professionals to answer, that's fine.

From the [FAQs](https://dba.stackexchange.com/faq) page:

> Database Administrators - Stack
>   Exchange is for **database professionals**
>   who wish to improve their database
>   skills and learn from others in the
>   community

PS: I wonder how many times I need to advise on [reading FAQs and About page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61039/what-advice-would-you-give-beginners-joining-a-stack-exchange-site/64943#64943).

Answer (score 2):

What about smaller embedded databases (eg sql-lite) where there isn't really an 'admin' focus. They probably fit more into pure programming. Single-user (or thread) isn't a good line-in-the-sand either as that can be applied to large data warehouses as well as small apps.